# what causes an electron to jump out of its orbit?

Tags: electrons

I was just wondering for an assignment what causes an electron to jump out of its own orbit. I hope someone could help me with this question.

Comment: Nothing can cause an electron to jump (which it can't do) out of an orbit (which it does not have). An atom can exchange a photon with an electromagnetic field which can change the electronic state of that atom. Now that is something that can and does happen.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons jump out of their orbit when they gain enough energy to escape the attraction from nucleus.

This energy can be pumped in by us or when electrons collide elastically they transform energy.

Conductors and semi-conductors work because electrons jump out of their orbit by getting energy.Movement of electrons is what conducts current.

(This is my first answer, as I'm new to this site. Please correct me if I'm wrong as I'm very keen to develop knowledge about physics). Regards.